# Problems loading mnist in tensorflow on Mac OS

Tags: macos, machine-learning, tensorflow

Please help, I encountered the following errors while attempting to download the MNIST dataset with Tensorflow.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Downloading data from https://s3.amazonaws.com/img-datasets/mnist.npz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 207, in get_file
    urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 248, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lorin/Applications/miniconda3/envs/udemy/mnist_keras.py", line 13, in <module>
    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data('/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/datasetsmnist.py')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/datasets/mnist.py", line 15, in load_data
    path = get_file(path, origin='https://s3.amazonaws.com/img-datasets/mnist.npz')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 209, in get_file
    raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://s3.amazonaws.com/img-datasets/mnist.npz: None -- [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
```

Process finished with exit code `enter code here`

Comment: You're going to want to show your code and also format your post using code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you install TensorFlow in a separate [virtualenv](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/).

Follow the following steps here: [Installing TensorFlow with virtualenv](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac)

> And always remember to activate the `virtualenv` environment each time you use TensorFlow in a new shell by running:
>    `$ source ~/<target_directory>/bin/activate`

Comment: I'm running in `virtualenv` and I get this too:
`
    >>> mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)
`

Comment: Virtualenv is not the solution. As noted by Peteris below, do /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command
instead.

Comment: Indeed. Thinking of deleting, or maybe I'll leave this here for historical purposes.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and the command below (as indicated in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10779) helped:

`/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command`

Comment: Thank you, that helped. Only the version '3.6' in the path might need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest version of Pip and the issue was fixed

Update using the following command:
"pip install --upgrade pip"

TensorFlow 2 packages require a pip version >19.0.